# How to echo something every 4 minutes while in an endless loop

Tags: php

I have a script that uses `while(true)` to run so it runs forever until it dies. I want to be able to make it echo something once every 4 minutes, how can i do this? The script runs on command prompt and it uses `while(true)` so its confusing plus i am not sure how to make it do that every 4 minutes.
 How can i make it echo something once every 4 minutes while still in a `while(true)`?

Comment: maybe sleep or delay function

Comment: Are you trying to spawn a server process to do some work from PHP or is this a local script that you are executing?

Answer (score 7):

You can try

```
while(true)
{
    sleep(240); // sleep for 240 sec
    echo " Hello World" ;
}
```

Or

```
$time = time();
while ( true ) {
    /*
     * Play Some Ball
     */

    if ((time() - $time) >= 240) {
        echo date("Y:m:d g:i:s"), PHP_EOL;
        $time = time();
    }
    sleep(2);
}
```

Output Test with `Time = 2 sec, Sleep =  1 sec`

```
2012:10:14 12:50:56
2012:10:14 12:50:58
2012:10:14 12:51:00
2012:10:14 12:51:02
2012:10:14 12:51:04
2012:10:14 12:51:06
2012:10:14 12:51:08
2012:10:14 12:51:10
2012:10:14 12:51:12
2012:10:14 12:51:14
```

Comment: i cant make it sleep because i need it active.

Comment: I would always recommend a small sleep on a tight loop that will run forever.  That or some other yielding method to avoid an all-consuming loop.

Comment: @jheddings  i totally agreed with you ... Nice one

Comment: @jheddings Too bad have exceeded by daily reputation ... Thanks  :)

Comment: yup small sleep to give job scheduler a change using something like usleep.

Answer (score 4):

Using a [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) method will actually halt your script from running. I'm not 100% if this is what you want to happen.

Another way to attack this issue would be to compare timestamps from the last "echo" command on each iteration.

```
$echo_time = time();
$interval = 4*60;
while(true){
  if ($echo_time + $interval >= time()){
    echo "$interval seconds have passed...";
    $echo_time = time(); // set up timestamp for next interval
  }
  // other uninterrupted code goes here.
}
```

This will allow your code within your loop to continue running and only check the times at the start of each iteration.

Comment: In php7 
`echo "$interval seconds have passed..."; `
should be:
`echo $interval . "seconds have passed...";`
Or:
`echo $interval . 'seconds have passed...'; // single quot is faster than double quot`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding in a loop of `while(true) { ... }` sleep() parameter function.

```
$sleep = 4*60;
while(true)
{
    # waiting...        
    sleep($sleep);
    # work after 240 mins
}
```