# PHP random every hour

Tags: php, arrays, random, sorting

My php is rusty, I am trying to get a PHP code to return a different user ID's added to the following array from an array of possible users.

```
'online_users'            => array(54)
'bots_ids'                => array(153,122,173,124,173,132,184,188)
```

I want to pick and a add random bot every 1-5 hours after which he will be replaced by another bot or just deleted (not all bots have to be online simutaniously)

I tried setting the seed to the current hours divided by a random number but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Every  `1hr` or every `5hr` or every `1hr to 5hr` ????

Comment: I was thinking about setting a seed of the current hour before using random. I think it would be easier to just do it once an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a array_rand() in this case. It will select up to N random keys out of the array and place them in their own array. This will let you do what you're looking to do .

```
$online_bots = array('4','5','6');
$bot_ids = array('1','2','3');

$random_bots = array_rand($bot_ids,1); // Random id from list
$bot_going_offline = array_shift($online_bots); // pop a bot from online

$online_bots[]= $bot_ids[$random_bots]; // add random bot from list
$bot_ids[] = $bot_going_offline; // move the oldest online bot into common pool
```

As for the 2nd part of the question, you can setup cron to execute the script at every hour that would trigger the change. Alternatively, to Online/Offline List you can just have a common pool of bots that gets randomly picked every hour.

```
$num_bots = rand ( 0, count($bot_ids));
$random_bots = array_rand($bot_ids,1); // Random id from list
for ($x = 0; X< $num_bots; x++)
   $online[] = $bot_ids[$random_bots[$x]];
```

Comment: Also wanted to mention that count($bot_ids) is just the max upper limit.

Comment: Can I make the results stay the same every hour by using 'srand(date('h:i'));?' Just seems more logical and easy

Answer (score 0):

A. You can use `cron job` to call your script every hour ... to get the random `bots` can be easily done with `array_rand`

```
$bots = array(153,122,173,124,173,132,184,188);
$current = $bots[array_rand($bots)];
var_dump($current);
```

B. If yout have a continues loop you should look at [How to echo something every 4 minutes while in an endless loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12877701/1226894) and replace echo with your random selector